# Setting state inside promise and outside promise affects on rendering component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-state

I have used axios and promise for fetching data. What I noticed is when I put setState() function out of promise i.e. in then() function, child component doesn't render. But when I put same setState() function inside of promise then child component renders perfectly.

setState() inside promise

```
    axios({
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'url',
            data: data
        }).then(function (response) {
            this.setState({
           stateItem: response.data.obj
    })}.bind(this)).catch(error){
console.log(error);
}
```

Above program can renders `stateItem` perfectly.

setState() outside promise

```
let val = 0;
axios({
       method: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       url: 'url',
       data: data
     }).then(function (response) {
        val = response.data[0].value;
        }.bind(this)).catch(error){
          console.log(error);
    } 
this.setState({ stateItem: val })
```

State updates perfectly but component which depends on that state doesn't update. Can anyone elaborate me why this happens? What happens in the background?

Comment: Where have you defined this request?

Comment: due to asynchronous, when you put setState inside promise it first call your api then get response and set the response to state, and in second case when you put setState outside the promise it will execute axios request and setState at same time.

Comment: @chauhanamit In both conditions state updates but there is difference between rendering the component. When setState() is inside promise, child component renders then why in second condition child component didn't render?

Comment: @JosephD. response value doesn't change. State value also not change. Just problem occurs while rendering the child component which is dependent on that particular state.

Comment: @IshanJoshi I didn't get you. It is defined outside of constructor and not defined in lifecycle methods.

Comment: your second code snippet have syntax error, it will give error because response is not defined outside the promise as you are trying to set response outside the axios promise. second setState causes re-render so when you put the setState inside the promise it will re-render the child with response data, but in case of outside it can not re-render any data because response is not defined also it will execute first and axios request will take more time to execute rather than setState.

Comment: @JosephD. See state value changes as I can see changed state value in console but child component which is dependent on that state value doesn't render.

Comment: @RohitSawai, can you add how are you passing this component's state to child components?

Comment: @Ashmah In usual way - `<ChildComp childProp = {this.state.stateItem} />`

Comment: @JosephD. I have changed code. Please again look into it. I have fixed bugs

Comment: Axios returns a promise, and promises are asynchronous, so in the second example since it doesn't appear you `await` the promise to resolve, javascript happily keeps chugging through the function and sets state to the current value of `val`, which you set to `0`.

Comment: @DrewReese No it doesn't set to 0. Value updates and state as well. I have checked. Problem occurs when it comes to rendering the child component

Comment: @RohitSawai could you share a working sandbox?

Comment: setState() inside promise: `.then(function` - there is no matching closing bracket

Comment: @winwiz1 I have updated the code. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

it is an asynchronous function, so the val won't be updated until the promise is resolved and state will be set before promise is resolved

```
let val = 0;
axios({
   method: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   url: 'url',
   data: data
 }).then(function (response) {
    val = response.data[0].value;
    this.setState({ stateItem: val })
    }.bind(this)).catch(error){
      console.log(error);
}
```

set the state like this

Comment: I have used async and await as well for resolving promise first. But that also didn't work for me.

Comment: See I have understood what you wanted to say. Just tell me one thing, why async and await didn't work in my case as in await part, promise resolves completely and then the code after it, executes.